# Promoted results not showing

Tags: search, search-results, promoted-links, best-bets, promoted-results

I am trying to set a promoted results on SP2013, but I can get it to show.

This is what I have done:

1. I have created a result source based on a site collection. This is marked as a Local SharePoint, SharePoint Search Results and the query is : {searchTerms} site:http://SERVERNAME/sites/ITS*
2. Created query rule based on the same result source. I did not change anything in Context. The query condition is "Query Matches Keyword Excatly" and just one single word. The promoted result is edited with a title, URL and desc. No result block is added. Under publishing it shows Is Active.

Now when I go to the search site and type in that ONE word that is specified in the query condition, and under the correct page for the selected result source, it does not show any promoted results. How is that? I have tried setting this up  both in Site Settings and Central Administration.

Any ideas what I might be overlooking here?

Comment: On your Query Rule's settings did you activate the `This block is always shown above core results` option?

Comment: @moe I did now. I had to add a result block and chose "This block is always shown above core results". This is not an option with just regular promoted result. Anyway, that did not work. I can add that I try to test the query in Manage Query Rules site and the query works just fine there.

Comment: Promoted Results always show at the top. Did you choose the correct Result Source for your rule? If you want it to show on the Everything page you have to choose Local SharePoint (System)

Comment: @MatthewMcDermott Hmm. It works when I set the Result Source to "Local SharePoint (system)", but not when I set it to my own ITS (system) as a source. ITS is a site collection. This is how I set up the Result Source: Pic1: http://postimg.org/image/qyw3k98ut/bb1a9c12/ Pic2: http://postimg.org/image/8ouv2w6kd/ Pic3: http://postimg.org/image/ihu5rhwyl/ (Servername is changed for security)

Comment: The main results page uses Local SharePoint. That's why it works. I am not clear on why you have the Result Source in the mix.

Comment: @MatthewMcDermott Don't I have to set up a custom result source if I want the promoted result to be only valid for one specific site collection etc?

Comment: No, the promoted result is configured for the search settings of the site collection.

Comment: @MatthewMcDermott I followed this video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3cZGoJ2P1-g Step by step. Is this wrong?

Comment: Can you tell me the time code? What Search Vertical do you want your Promoted Result to appear on?

Comment: @MatthewMcDermott Time code? What do you mean? I want it to appear on a Search Vertical called ITS, witch is also a site collection by the same name.

Comment: What part of the video, I don't have the time to watch the full hour. At what TIME does the tip appear?

Comment: Ahh. Sorry. :) 41.36 the relevant demo starts.

Comment: @MatthewMcDermott Did you get the time to watch it?